# compare and check the order of the two maps

Tags: java

I have a zodiac map that stores the zodiac sign with following order

```
Map<String,String> ZodiacMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
zodiacMap.put("Aries", "March 21 - April 19");
zodiacMap.put("Taurus", "April 20 - May 20");
zodiacMap.put("Gemini", "May 21 - June 20");
zodiacMap.put("Cancer", "June 21 - July 22");
zodiacMap.put("Leo", "July 23 - August 22");
zodiacMap.put("Virgo", "August 23 - September 22");
zodiacMap.put("Libra", "September 23 - October 22");
zodiacMap.put("Scorpio", "October 23 - November 21");
zodiacMap.put("Capricorn", "November 22 - December 21");
zodiacMap.put("Aquarius", "January 20 - February 18");
zodiacMap.put("Pisces", "February 19 - March 20");
```

In UI some zodiac signs are added as favorite and keeping that in another map with added zodiacs will be listed on the top of the map.

Here `Tarus,Libra,Scrorpio,Aquarius` added as favorites

I have to verify the zodiac signs added as favorite are in the sorted order also at the same time verify the remaining zodiac's are in the sorted order.

```
zodiacMap1.put("Taurus", "April 20 - May 20");
zodiacMap1.put("Libra", "September 23 - October 22");
zodiacMap1.put("Scorpio", "October 23 - November 21");
zodiacMap1.put("Aquarius", "January 20 - February 18");

zodiacMap1.put("Aries", "March 21 - April 19");
zodiacMap1.put("Gemini", "May 21 - June 20");
zodiacMap1.put("Cancer", "June 21 - July 22");
zodiacMap1.put("Leo", "July 23 - August 22");
zodiacMap1.put("Virgo", "August 23 - September 22");
zodiacMap1.put("Capricorn", "November 22 - December 21");
zodiacMap1.put("Pisces", "February 19 - March 20");
```

I dont know how to write a logic for the ablove proble.
Please provide a sample code also.

Also is there any other ways to do this.other than using map(like enum?)

Comment: This better be an Enum instead of a Map

Comment: I don't understand the requirement. Could you expand more on what you want to do and what is the problem you're facing?

Comment: I have to find the zodiac sign added to favorite and the remaining zodiacs are in the same order (month vice)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an `enum` that makes it possible to compare with the begin dates. I just added `Aries` for the example, but the goal is to have all Zodiac signs.

[java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8)

```
enum Zodiac {
    Aries("March 21", "April 19");

    LocalDate begin, end;
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM DD");

    Zodiac(String begin, String end){
        this.begin = LocalDate.parse(begin, dtf);
        this.end = LocalDate.parse(end, dtf);
    }

    public int compareToOtherZodiac(Zodiac o) {
        return this.begin.compareTo(o.begin);
    }
}
```

---

[java-7](/questions/tagged/java-7)

```
enum Zodiac {
    Aries("March 21", "April 19");

    Date begin, end;
    DateFormat dtf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM DD");

    Zodiac(String begin, String end) {
        try {
            this.begin = dtf.parse(begin);
            this.end = dtf.parse(end);
        } catch (ParseException pe) {
            pe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public int compareToOtherZodiac(Zodiac o) {
        return this.begin.compareTo(o.begin);
    }
}
```

Comment: Very elegant solution. Nice!

Comment: but one problem is i cant use like Aries("21-03", "19-04"); coz real data coming is in the form of ("Aries", "March 21 - April 19").

Comment: @PSl Not a problem. Edited it :)

Comment: the method parse(String, DateTimeFormatter) is undefined for the type LocalDate

Comment: @Psl [It is, check this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-). Are you using [tag:java-8] ?

Comment: @Psl OK I'll try to come with an answer for you than. LocalDate is only used in java-8

Comment: i have to use this code both in java 7 and java 8...so?

Comment: @Psl The code I originally posted works for Java8 only. I'll try to adapt it to Java7 also

Comment: actually my main intention is after adding some zodiacs to favorites i will get an xml response  that contains the list of zodiacs .and am parsing the xml for getting the zodiac sign with "March 21 - April 19" and keeping it in a map.So what am asking is can i compare that list with enum defined above and confirm zodiacs are in proper order ???

Comment: @Psl Here it is. Well using this Enum and `valueOf()` it would be simple.

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it you should use a LinkedHashMap with the exact same logic. It will maintain the order of insertion.

A TreeMap with a custom comparator could also be used but the favorites would be difficult to remain at top.